# Sound Detection with GoLang

Tags: go, audio

I am working on creating a very simple and lightweight solution for what would basically be a Golang sound detector. I need to read a MP3/MP4 audio stream (working with a file for now) and preforming a function I have when louder than usual sound is detected. I am relatively new to Golang and have no experience with digital audio. I have the code below that detects a beep, but don't know how to go about detecting just louder noises and not just a beep. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "math/cmplx"
    "net/http"

    "os"

    "github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/oto"

    "github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/fft"

    "github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/window"
)

// const sampleRate = 44100
const toneFrequency = 440
const mp3file = "C:/Users/mmekaiel/Music/audio-samples/440Hz.mp3"

func serveHome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<h1>Hello world site!!</h1>")
}

func serveAudio(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("<h1>The <a href='https://github.com/rwarford/simple-tone-detect'>tone-detect</a> audio page!!</h1>"))

    if err := process(toneFrequency); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func process(toneFreq int) error {
    f, err := os.Open(mp3file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    d, err := mp3.NewDecoder(f)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    p, err := oto.NewPlayer(d.SampleRate(), 2, 2, 8192)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer p.Close()

    windowSize := 40 // window size in milliseconds
    windowSamples := int(float32(d.SampleRate()) * float32(windowSize) / 1000.0)

    // fftSize is the smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to windowSamples
    fftSize := int(math.Pow(2, math.Ceil(math.Log2(float64(windowSamples)))))

    spectralWidth := float64(d.SampleRate()) / float64(fftSize)
    targetIndex := int(float64(toneFreq) / spectralWidth)

    fmt.Printf("Sample Rate: %d\n", d.SampleRate())
    fmt.Printf("Length: %d[bytes]\n", d.Length())
    fmt.Printf("Window size: %d[samples]\n", windowSamples)
    fmt.Printf("FFT size: %d\n", fftSize)
    fmt.Printf("Spectral Line width: %v[hertz]\n", spectralWidth)
    fmt.Printf("Tone index: %d\n", targetIndex)

    b := make([]byte, windowSamples*4) // 2 bytes per sample, 2 channels
    w := make([]float64, fftSize)
    t := 0
    toneStart := -1

outerloop:
    for {
        // Read a window of samples
        bytesRead := 0
        for bytesRead < len(b) {
            n, err := d.Read(b[bytesRead:])
            if err != nil {
                break outerloop
            }
            bytesRead += n
        }

        // Convert to float (ignore second channel)
        for i := 0; i < len(b); i += 4 {
            w[i/4] = float64(int16(binary.LittleEndian.Uint16(b[i+0:i+2]))) / 32768.0
        }

        // Apply window function
        window.Apply(w, window.Hamming)

        // Perform FFT
        c := fft.FFTReal(w)

        // Compute the normalized magnitude
        r, _ := cmplx.Polar(c[targetIndex])
        r = r / float64(fftSize)

        // Look for tone
        toneDetected := r > 0.05 // Apply arbitrary threshold
        if toneDetected && toneStart < 0 {
            toneStart = t
        } else if !toneDetected && (toneStart >= 0) {
            fmt.Printf("Tone from %dms to %dms.\n", toneStart, t)
            toneStart = -1
        }

        t += windowSize
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    mux := &http.ServeMux{}

    mux.HandleFunc("/", serveHome)

    mux.HandleFunc("/audio", serveAudio)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mp3 library you are using decodes an mp3 into ["Raw"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_audio_format) audio, which is usually [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation). The documentation for the [NewDecoder](https://godoc.org/github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3#NewDecoder) also mentions

> The stream is always formatted as 16bit (little endian) 2 channels even if the source is single channel MP3. Thus, a sample always consists of 4 bytes.

From that, you can look up the exact format of the sound data. It looks like it is just as simple as 16 bits left, 16 bits right, repeat. This value is turned into the position of the speaker diaphragm.

To look for volume, you should look for a large value, or maybe a large change in value since last frame. You don't need the FTT stuff. That's an operation known as "[fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)". It allows you to see what frequencies are currently in the sound. That's useful for determining the pitch of a note, but not useful at all in determining volume. I would remove just about everything after the decoder, and try to just read some bytes from it.

EDIT: After further thought, a loud sound takes place over a much longer time than a single sample (digital audio isn't my field). [-This is how you actually do it-](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46147/how-to-get-the-volume-level-from-pcm-audio-data)

Also Note: the 16 bits can be signed or unsigned (s16le or u16le). It looks like signed is the 'standard' and likely.

EDIT 2: Unless you are developing a sound processing library, I would recommend finding one yourself. I personally use GStreamer for this sort of thing, but it's waaaay overkill for what you need (I do *not* recommend it).

Maybe something like [PCM Datatype library](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-audio/audio). They seem to do some gain amplification and scaling in [here](https://github.com/go-audio/transforms). Looks like a good place to dig.